# R.id.webview error: cannot find symbol in MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, webview

Good day,

I am doing a `cordova` mobile app, and I am trying to access to `webview` to configure something. I google around, the way to get the `webview` object is something as follow:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

I put this code in my MainActivity.java, but I hit error when I trying to build my code:
[image]

I google around and found that many post was asking to check in the `layout file` and the `activity_main file`, but I do not have any of these file in my workspace. I am new to frontend development so maybe I may have some miss understand on some solution from internet.

Can anyone advise me on this?

Comment: Where's your xml code?

Comment: Hi @DrMido, May I know which xml code?
is it the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: the xml file that contains `webview` that you're trying to bind it with `this.findViewById(R.id.webview);`

Comment: hi @DrMido , I actually search for whole workspace, no have any wording of "webview" being found. I thought the `this.findViewById(R.id.webview);` is some kind of the android library code that can use in MainActivity.java.

Comment: If you don't see any file containing the `webview` then you cannot use it in the java class, I think there's something missing in your project try to figure out

Comment: Thanks @DrMido. let me check it out. By the way, may I know is `webview` mandatory for cordova mobile project? I would like to find out is it I miss out the `webview` configuration in some where, or my project is actually some kind of "non-webview" project.